# How expensive is reading files though PHP for access control

Tags: php

I need to control access to files and would like to have an opinion on how efficient the following setup is, and if there is a better approach.

I am passing all image requests through an intermediary php file, that checks permissions, if the file exists, and then reads the file back to the browser. I am using this for images and other files as well. Within this file, I also check if the browser I requesting a thumbnail and create it if it does not exist.

```
<img src="get-file.php?id=1234" />
```

get-file.php ( modified for this example )

```
  $id= $_GET['id'];


  if( !$is_thumbnail_request ){
     // don't check permission for thumbnail images
     $this->checkPermission($id);
  }


  $file=$this->model->getFile($id);

  if (file_exists($file['file'])){

    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $file['file']);
    finfo_close($finfo);
    header("Content-Type:".$mime);

    readfile($file['file']);

  }


function checkPermission( $id ){
  // checks MySql database for access
}
```

Thanks!
Ben

Comment: You need to show `checkPermission()` for us to guess how efficient it is.

Comment: checkPermission() is only called when returning a full sized file. The function makes a database call to check for permission. I am mainly asking if it is a bad idea to check for files existing read image files though php the this way for every protected file on the page.

Comment: What's the alternative? If you don't check, you'll allow security violations.

Comment: I don't know of one ... I just wanted a dummy check.